# Use Frobenius' method to find two independent solutions to the ODE $4tx''(t)+2x'(t)+x(t)=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

It is known that $t=0$ is a regular singular point of

$4tx''(t)+2x'(t)+x(t)=0$.

By Frobenius' method, show that two independent solutions of the ODE are given by

$x_1(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^k$ and $x_2(t)=\sqrt{t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty$$\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^k$

--

So far I have used the Frobenius ansatz $x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^{k+r}$ which implies

$x'(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r)a_kt^{k+r-1}$ and

$x''(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r-1)(k+r)a_kt^{k+r-2}$

Substituting into the ODE gives

$4\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r-1)(k+r)a_kt^{k+r-1}+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r)a_kt^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^{k+r}=0$

We can then change the summation index to make all of the powers of $t$ in each summation equal to $k+r-1$:

$4\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r-1)(k+r)a_kt^{k+r-1}+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r)a_kt^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k-1}t^{k+r-1}=0$

Which we can combine to make:

$4(r-\frac{1}{2})ra_0t^{r-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^{k+r-1}(a_k(4(k+r-\frac{1}{2})(k+r))+a_{k-1})$

It is here that I am unsure of what to do. I believe I need to find the indicial equation? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\color {blue}{4(r-\frac{1}{2})ra_0t^{r-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^{k+r-1}(a_k(4(k+r-\frac{1}{2})(k+r))+a_{k-1})=0$$

Yes you need to find the indicial equation. Take the coefficient of the lowest power of $t$. You should get for all $t$:

$$t^ {r-1} (4ra_0(r-1)+2ra_0)=0$$
$$2ra_0(2r-1)=0$$
$$r(2r-1)=0$$
$$\implies r=0,r=\frac 12$$

What you have done is correct. Now you have the values of $r$ you can continue.

Next step: you have  to find the recurrence relation and deduce, if it is possible, a recurrence formula and find the series solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I have now obtained the recurrence relation: $a_k=\frac{-a_{k-1}}{2(2k+2r-1)(k+r)}$. How would I transfer this into finding the formula, and ultimately the series solutions?

Comment: You're welcome. Oh you have two case depending on r....Plug the values of r and see if you find a pattern @mathemagic

Comment: By the way I checked tje solution you posted didnt you miss a t inside the series ? @mathemagic

Comment: My bad! Very sorry, I'll edit it to avoid confusion from any other readers. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: For $r=0$ and $r=1/2$ you get the same recurrence formula you have after that to split into cosine and sin function...Even and Od power of t...@mathemagic . I did the calculation from you recurrence formula and I get the correct answer. you are close to finich this problem.

Comment: Note that an important thing that your recurrence is valid for $k \ge 1$ @mathemagic

Comment: I have found the patterns now, and have got my two formulae: $a_m=\frac{(-1)^ma_0}{(2m)!}$ for $r=0$ and $a_m=\frac{(-1)^ma_0}{(2m+1)!}$ for $r=\frac{1}{2}$, how do I know that the values of $a_0$ are $1$ and $\sqrt{t}$ respectively? Thanks!

Comment: Good job @mathemagic ...$a_0$ is a constant. You need inital conditions for that and you are not given any intial conditions. Keep it that way..

Comment: Thanks. The question says the two independent solutions are $x_1(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^k$ and $x_2(t)=\sqrt{t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^k$ but where they have a $1$ and a $\sqrt{t}$ I have $a_0$. Am I missing something or is it just that the constant can be set to whatever you like?

Comment: we add two constants for $x(t)=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ with differential equations thats the rule. . @mathemagic  Dont' forget to multiply you series by $t^r$ I mean $t^0$ and $t^{1/2}$ for the other series

Comment: I see it now! I need to substitute these back into the original ansatz and I will get the coefficients they are looking for as the $t^r$ terms can be brought outside the summation! Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome @mathemagic One series is from the recurrence formula for $r=1/2$ multiply that series by $\sqrt t$ Because with frobenius method the series is of the form $t^r \sum a_nt^n$

Comment: I think I still get an $a_0$ out at the front of the summation though, whereas their answers do not. This is the last piece of the puzzle I think!

Comment: It's a constant it dosent matter @mathemagic For a differnetial equation that is linear if $e^t$ is a solution then $2e^t$ is also a solution and also $c_1e^t$

Comment: I see, so it is absorbed into the other constants you mentioned earlier! Thank you and stay safe!

Comment: Yes these are constants. Thank you stay safe too. Take care. @mathemagic

Answer (score 3):

To find the indicial equation, you begin by putting it in standard form: $$x'' + (1/2t)x' + (1/4t)x = x'' + p(t)x' + q(t)x = 0$$

The indicial equation is $$r(r-1) + p_0r + q_0 = 0$$ where $$ p_0 = \lim_{t \to 0}t \,p(t) \\ q_0 = \lim_{t \to 0} t^2 \, q(t) $$